# No shell for ssh connection after proper password entered

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have two hosts with 20.04 Testing in same wifi subnet connected to my AP.
I wanted to have secured transfer of files betwen them so I choose sh/scp.
When I connect from one to another, I enter right password, hit enten, and nothing shows for minutes. Same action from host two to one give same results.

```
$ ssh user@ip -v
.....
i@192.168.43.59's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).  
Authenticated to 192.168.43.59 ([192.168.43.59]:22).  
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]  
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com  
debug1: Entering interactive session.  
debug1: pledge: network  
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com
 want_reply 0  
debug1: Sending environment.  
debug1: Sending env LANG = pl_PL.UTF-8  
----end-------
```

ssh service ssh status:

```
lut 23 16:02:11 W540 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...  
lut 23 16:02:11 W540 sshd[2398]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.  
lut 23 16:02:11 W540 sshd[2398]: Server listening on :: port 22.  
lut 23 16:02:11 W540 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.  
lut 23 17:11:13 W540 sshd[31356]: Accepted password for adi from 192.168.43.16 port 41698 ssh2
```

What can be the reason that I do not receive bash prompt?

Comment: Is the `pl_PL.UTF-8` locale installed on the target system? Try with `LANG=C.UTF-8 ssh user@ip -v`

Comment: I expect that locales are installed, when I press Alt + a, I get ą etc. so letters in terminal are right. I used your sugestion about adding LANG= as above and I was able to get console with Bash and prompt ready. On another computer first I connected as previous without LANG= and it works now. I checked on first one and also work without. One thing that I can imagine that both computers were turned off and some transient state was cleared.Also sftp works fine